# Installed packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, dpkg

When i tried to install lxc-docker-0.7.6 on ubuntu 13.04, i get the following errors:

```
The  following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libsdl-ttf2.0-0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lxc-docker-0.7.6
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2,681 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://get.docker.io/ubuntu/ docker/main lxc-docker-0.7.6 amd64 0.7.6 [2,681 kB]
Fetched 2,681 kB in 3s (857 kB/s)             
(Reading database ... 171665 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking lxc-docker-0.7.6 (from .../lxc-docker-0.7.6_0.7.6_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/lxc-docker-0.7.6_0.7.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/docker', which is also in package docker 1.4-5ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/lxc-docker-0.7.6_0.7.6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below commands on terminal,

```
sudo dpkg -r docker
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: sudo dpkg -r docker worked...